# "The maximum of empty set is less than 1"

Tags: logic

Is this statement true because the empty set has no maximum element or false because there isn't a specific element you can say is the maximum of the empty set that is less than 1.

Comment: I don't think it's true. What you can say is the least upper bound is less than $1$.

Comment: One may adopt the natural convention that the maximum of the empty set is $-\infty$. With this convention, the proposition is true. Otherwise it is undefined.

Comment: It seems to like it must be either false or meaningless.  To say it's true is, I think, to interpret as meaning "If $x$ is the maximum of the empty set, then $x<1$" but it seems more natural to interpret it as meaning "$\exists x$ such that $x$ is the maximum of the  empty set and $x<1$."

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a natural convention for the supremum of the empty set, but the maximum is usually required to be an element of the set, isn't it?  This statement seems to me to be of the same type as, "The King of the United States is over seven feet tall."

Comment: @saulspatz: negotiable. Note that Burger King is an American company.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: a burger seven feet tall? Who can eat  that?